# the greater functor doesn't work

Tags: c++, templates, generics, stl, functor

Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b=2;
    if(greater<int>(a,b))
        cout<<"YES";
    else
        cout<<"NO";
}
```

When I compile it, the error message is: error C2661: “std::greater<_Ty>::greater”:no overloaded function that takes two parameters. This is confusing, it should take two parameters, right?

I use greater with sort algorithm, it works perfectly fine. But I don't know how this error message in the above program comes about.

Comment: `std::greater` is a class template. You need to create an instance first, i.e. `std::greater<int>()(a,b)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::greater`'s comparison functionality is done through its `operator()` or the function call operator. With you doing

```
greater<int>(a,b)
```

you are creating a `greater<int>` object and not doing a comparison. The error actually says that there is no constructor accepting two `int`s because you are attempting to create an object of it.

Create first a `greater<int>` object then use its function call operator

```
greater<int>()(a, b)
//          |/|----|
//          | |
//          | |- Then call greater<int>::operator() which does the comparison 
//          |- Create a temporary greater<int> object
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6574bebfcfb3d0be)

Comment: @richard.g If this answers your question, consider accepting an answer by clicking the grey check mark next to it. This would let others know  that you are no longer actively looking for an improved solution, and earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

It will work this way :

```
int a = 1;
int b=2;
greater<int> g;
if(g(a,b))
cout<<"YES";
else
cout<<"NO";
```

Answer (score 1):

Write it the following way

```
if(greater<int>()(a,b))
```

To compare values class std::greater uses its operator function